# how to download or convert dataframe into excel file?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, utf-8, base64

trying to convert or download dataframe into excel file with arabic data.

But when i run the script the system crash and display the below error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
Traceback:
File "F:\AIenv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 333, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "f:\AIenv\streamlit\app2.py", line 712, in <module>
    main()
File "f:\AIenv\streamlit\app2.py", line 250, in main
    transform(df)
File "f:\AIenv\streamlit\app2.py", line 178, in transform
    download_file(df, types, new_types, "xls")
File "f:\AIenv\streamlit\app2.py", line 141, in download_file
    b64 = base64.b64encode(excel.encode()).decode("utf-8")
```

## code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import base64
        
data=pd.DataFrame({
           "SourceNo":[11192,11193,11194],
          "IssuedDate":['3/15/2021','3/15/2021','3/15/2021'],
          نوع":["هاتف","تلفاز","سماعة"]",
          مكان الحدث":["حي السلم","منطقة الشمال","ميناء"]", 
          التاريخ":["3/15/2021","3/15/2021","3/15/2021"]",
          أشخاص":["مواطنون","مواطنون","مجهول"]"
             })  

        df=pd.read_excel(data)
        excel = df.to_excel(r"F:\update2.xlsx", index = False, header=True,encoding="utf-8")
        b64 = base64.b64encode(excel.encode()).decode("utf-8")
```

where is the error in this code?

Comment: Can you please provide the data

Comment: I EDIT  my question and add image as a sample of  the `data`

Comment: Can you provide it in the code format?

Answer (score 0):

[to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) method is used for exporting dataframe into an excel file. It is a void method, therefore it does not return anything. You try to get the return value into a variable named excel, and since the method does not return anything the excel variable is equal to None. That is the reason of the error.

Comment: ok so how to fix the error and assign `excel` variable to the correct value?

Answer (score 0):

The `.to_excel` method writes a file and returns `None`.  If you want the file content encoded in base64, read it back in:

```py
import pandas as pd 
import base64

df = pd.DataFrame({'SourceNo':[11192,11193,11194],
                   'IssuedDate':['3/15/2021','3/15/2021','3/15/2021'],
                   'نوع':['هاتف','تلفاز','سماعة'],
                   'مكان الحدث':['حي السلم','منطقة الشمال','ميناء'],
                   'التاريخ':['3/15/2021','3/15/2021','3/15/2021'],
                   'أشخاص':['مواطنون','مواطنون','مجهول']})

df.to_excel('update2.xlsx', index = False, header=True,encoding='utf-8')

with open('update2.xlsx','rb') as f:
    b64 = base64.b64encode(f.read())
```